# How to get container spreadsheet ID from time-based trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a time-based trigger that was created by a spreadsheet-bound script (lets call the spreadsheet “spreadsheet A“).

The trigger triggers a code from a function found in a library (lets call the function “lib function 1”), *not* from the spreadsheet-bound script of “spreadsheet A”).

In “lib function 1”- How can I get the container spreadsheet’s ID?

I really need it! :)

Thanks!

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I haven’t. I assume there is a way to either get the project or trigger ID and the container from there, but I haven’t found it.

Comment: From the function in the library SpreadsheetA's id = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks. However, the spreadsheet is not necessarily active when the trigger fires.

Comment: Once you connect the library to the project they're essentially contained and I believe getActive() will return the container and thus it's id.

Comment: Unless you have a better idea. Try it.

Comment: I did. It returns null. The library is a standalone project. What allows the linkage of it’s code to the spreadsheet bound project is defining the library as a resource of the bound project. The trigger triggers the library function on a time where the spreadsheet is not active (it is in the middle of the night)

Comment: Thanks I didn’t know that

Comment: What’s interesting about that is that the trigger is a project trigger. So why would it trigger a function that is not in the project.

Comment: The purpose of the library is easy maintenance of an identical code in multiple project. This allows you to modify your code in one place, instead of in each project separately.

Comment: I just set up a timebased trigger to a bound function which called the library function while the spreadsheet was off and the library function wrote some data which included the spreadsheets id to my spreadsheet.

Comment: In what project can you view the created trigger?

Comment: I tried triggering the library function directly but that fails everytime and the listed name of the project on the trigger did not include the libraries name so it probably failed  because it couldn't find the function.

Comment: This might be the solution I am looking for (local function that calls library function)! I will try it when I’ll be near a computer and let you know. Thanks for the research :)

Comment: You can watch the project executions from the GSuite Developers Hub.  To see the triggers.  I ran mine for a while with 10 minute triggers.

Comment: Yes, I checked there. The trigger is executed from the spreadsheet bound project and triggers to library function (“LibraryName.functionName”)

Comment: Hi, it worked! Can you post the relevant comment as an answer so I can indicate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just set up a timebased trigger to a bound function which called the library function while the spreadsheet was off and the library function wrote some data which included the spreadsheets id to my spreadsheet.

Comment: This might be the solution I am looking for (local function that calls library function)! I will try it when I’ll be near a computer and let you know. Thanks for the research :)